# AngularJS Ghosting in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

Got a problem with an app wrote in AngularJS. Seems that in Internet Explorer I get ghosting of elements or elements not rendering correctly however in Firefox and Chrome it works perfectly. I updated AngularJS to 1.5.9 to see if it fixed any issues but however it doesn't. I've included an image of the issue below. If I resize the IE window then it redraws the elements and looks like the second picture. As mentioned this is only present in IE. Has anyone come across this before and knows how to fix it?

The issue [image: Image of the Issue]

What it should look like and does after resizing the window [image: What it should look like]

Comment: That seems to be a styling compatibility issue, not an Angular one. What version of IE are you testing against?

Comment: IE 11 - Tried changing the document modes too. Still the same